# Can you say "Our results speak for themselves" if you want to make clear that the results are obvious?

Tags: expressions, translation

Can you say "Our results speak for themselves" if you want to make clear that the results are obvious?
I want to translate something and I don't know if this phrase is too literally for the English language

Comment: Welcome to ELL! I'm really glad you got an answer you liked so quickly, but you might want to wait a while before selecting an answer. This post on meta explains some reasons why: [Not so fast! (When should I accept my answer?)](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1307/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To speak for itself/themselves is a very widely used English idiom.

> speaks for itself ​
>
> C2 If something speaks for itself, it is clear and
>   needs no further explanation:
>
> The school's excellent record speaks for itself.

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speaks-for-itself)

Answer (score 1):

This expression doesn't really mean that the results are obvious.  What it means is that because our results are good, then the **procedures and processes** we use to achieve those results must be good as well (otherwise those good results couldn't have been achieved).  Here's how this expression could be used in context:

> Q: I see that your company has been profitable for each of the past five years. Do you think this is because you have a better understanding of customer needs than your competition does?
>
> A: Well, I could show you all of the research our marketing team has done, but really, I think **our results speak for themselves.**

So here, A is not saying that the results are obvious, he's saying that the fact that the results are good means that it's obvious that the research has been good.